# What is the use of pkg directory in Go?

Tags: go

If we have bin directory already where executables go then what is the need of pkg directory? Please explain.

Comment: https://golang.org/doc/code.html#Workspaces

Comment: I researched the pkg details but could not grasp the concept of package objects

Answer (score 30):

The `pkg` directory contains Go package objects compiled from `src` directory Go source code packages, which are then used, at link time, to create the complete Go executable binary in the `bin` directory.

We can compile a package once, but link that object into many executables. For example, the `fmt` package appears in almost every Go program. It's compiled once but linked many times, a big saving.

Comment: So does this mean that packages other than main should go there

Comment: @dvsakgec: Yes. An executable command has one and only one `main` package. It is linked with other imported packages from the `pkg` directory to form the exectable in the `bin` directory. Packages other than `main` are compiled to object form and stored in the `pkg` directory, which is searched at link time for imported packages.

Comment: There are other uses for the pkg directory. See the answer by kyakya for more details.

Answer (score 11):

#### `~/go/pkg`

From [How to Write Go Code](https://golang.org/doc/code.html), we know `~/go/pkg` can store third party library. For example:

1. Create two file `main.go` and `go.mod`:

```
//main.go
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/google/go-cmp/cmp"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(cmp.Diff("Hello World", "Hello Go"))
}
```

```
//go.mod
module example.com/user/hello

go 1.13
```

2. Install a third party library

```
$ ls ~/go/pkg/mod/github.com/google/
...

$ go install example.com/user/hello
go: finding github.com/google/go-cmp v0.5.2
go: downloading github.com/google/go-cmp v0.5.2
go: extracting github.com/google/go-cmp v0.5.2

$ ls ~/go/pkg/mod/github.com/google/
... go-cmp@v0.5.2

$ ls ~/go/pkg/mod/github.com/google/go-cmp@v0.5.2
```

And then, you will see a lot of go files, not compile files.

```
$ ls ~/go/pkg/mod/github.com/google/go-cmp@v0.5.2/cmp/
...  example_test.go   options.go   ...
```

#### `pkg` in user project

This `pkg` is a directory/package of user project. You can see it as Library and it's OK to use by external applications. For more things, you can check [here](https://github.com/golang-standards/project-layout).

Comment: This is the most complete answer. See also https://github.com/golang-standards/project-layout. There are a number of useful links in this repo that further explain, and provide examples of, the pkg directory, including the history of pkg and the pros/cons of using it.

Answer (score 7):

You put your source code in `src` directory while `pkg` is the directory that holds compilation output of your actual source code. If you use multiple libraries/packages you will have different output with extension `.a` for each one, A `linker` should be responsible for linking and combining all of them together to produce one final executable in `bin` directory.

As `pkg` and `bin` are more specific to the machine or operating system into which you build your actual source code so it is not recommended to share both of them, your repo should have only your actual code.

A side note, if you plan to use docker containers, `pkg` dir should be ignored as we may build the source code in `windows` for example while you `import/mount` your code into `linux` container; at this time `pkg` will have compiled files that are only valid for `windows`

Comment: There are other uses for the pkg directory. See the answer by kyakya for additional details.